# Работа с ArrayList<BigInterger>

Tags: java

Как можно заполнить ArrayList сразу значениями? Например если бы был обычный тип данных, то с помощью Collections.addAll(...). По заданию надо заполнить переменные value1 и value2 так:
value1 = (a, 1, 0)
value2 = (b, 0, 1)

```
public static ArrayList<BigInteger> Euclid(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    if(a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> value1 = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        ArrayList<BigInteger> value2 = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    }
}
```

Как это можно сделать, 6 раз не вызывая value1.add()

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему. Вопрос непонятен.

Answer (score 0):

Следует использовать конструктор [`ArrayList<>(Collection<? extends E> collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)), принимающий на вход "начальную" коллекцию, которую можно формировать несколькими способами:

1. [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```java
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.math.BigInteger.ONE;
import static java.math.BigInteger.ZERO;

// ...

List<BigInteger> value1 = new ArrayList<>(asList(a, ONE, ZERO));
List<BigInteger> value2 = new ArrayList<>(asList(b, ZERO, ONE));
```

2. [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)) (Java 9+)

```java
List<BigInteger> value1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(a, ONE, ZERO));
List<BigInteger> value2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(b, ZERO, ONE));
```